# Does Spring Data JPA crudrepository save method have any return value? If so what does it returns?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

```
public void registerCustomer(Customer cust)
{
customerRepo.save(cust);
}
```

how can i know that my data is insereted successfully in my above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is from CrudReporsitory.save() javadoc:

> Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.

It seems like save method returns the saved entity instance.

Comment: it is returning the entity instance whether the data is added or not

Comment: @harish Is there any documentation about this statement?